# How to get Drive infos(ParentReference) to copy file to another drive using MS GRAPH SDK C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to copy a file from a drive to another using MS GRAPH SDK in C#.

I can successfuly do this by using hardcoded parentReference (DriveId & Id), because i retrieved this by getting the parentReference from an existing file in the destination drive.

"/sites/SiteId/drives/DriveId/root/children"

> ```
>         "parentReference": {
>             "driveId": "b!07UG1YX6EEWI-xYElkDOj9a5a_hmu6RDt0mpVQfH3RFpCR1wxODCRpss4Xq4g75t",
>             "driveType": "documentLibrary",
>             "id": "01QVACJXF6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
>             "path": "/drives/b!07UG1YX6EEWI-xYElkDOj9a5a_hmu6RDt0mpVQfH3RFpCR1wxODCRpss4Xq4g75t/root:"
>         },
> ```

My current code :

```
        var parentReference = new ItemReference
        {
            DriveId = destination.Id, //retrieved DriveId previously
            Id = "01QVACJXF6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
        };

        var name = DocumentTitle + "."+ extensionTemplate;

        var result = await graphClient.Sites[IdGestDoc].Drives[templateDrive.Id].Items[template.DriveItem.Id]
            .Copy(name, parentReference)
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();
```

But my question is how to get this informations when there is no existing files in the drive ?

I can retrieve the DriveId but not the Id for the parentReference..

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: So you want to copy files from one drive to another one that's empty?

Comment: yes that's it, the problem is that i can retrieve the DriveId (Id of the destination drive) but i don't find the Id used for parentReference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact [`Copy a DriveItem` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) expects `parentReference` parameter to be:

> Reference to the **parent item** the copy will be created in.

meaning, to copy a file into an empty drive, *target drive id* and *root folder of this drive* needs to be specified, like this:

```
var parentReference = new ItemReference
{
     DriveId = "--target drive-id-goes-here--",
     Id = "--root folder-of-drive-goes-here--"
};


 var result = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[driveId].Items[itemId]
 .Copy(name, parentReference)
 .Request()
 .PostAsync();
```

where *drive id* and its *root folder id* could be determined beforehand like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{target-drive-id}/root?select=id,parentReference


{
    "id": "--root-folder-id-of-drive",
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "--drive-id--",
        "driveType": "documentLibrary"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i was searching for a moment and i simply did not tried the /root endpoint on the target drive to get the root folder id..